# SAML does RequestedAttribute[FriendlyName] map to Attribute[Name]?

Tags: saml-2.0

When creating (SAML2.0) SP metadata, I can request attributes to be returned by the IdP. For example:

```
...
<md:AttributeConsumingService>
  <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="givenName"
                         Name="urn:oid.2.5.4.42"/>
</md:AttributeConsumingService>
...
```

On successful login, I will see this as part of AttributeStatement:

```
...
<saml2:AttributeStatement xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
   <saml2:Attribute Name="givenName">
      Tom
   </saml2:Attribute>
</saml2:AttributeStatement>
```

... I think.

Question is: Does my requested `Requested[FriendlyName]` value, in this case "givenName" map directly to the returned `Attribute[Name]` value?  That is, if I simply change FriendlyName's value to "FirstName", should I expect the returned Attribute to be named "FirstName" rather than "givenName"?

And, does such a change require a change on the IdP side? That is, should I expect that the IdP is "looking" at value of FriendlyName rather than the Name="urn:oid.2.5.4.42", or should it flow transparently through (a well built IdP)?

Or, is asserted attribute's Name tied to the requested Name oid & and if I request `Name="urn:oid.2.5.4.42"`, I'll get an asserted attribute `Name="givenName"`, always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IdP will return something similar to this:

```
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42" FriendlyName="givenName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
        <AttributeValue>Dave</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

The formal name of the attribute is `urn:oid:2.5.4.42` but it also has a human readable name which is 'givenName'. The FriendlyName is only for user interface things like showing the user what attributes have been released. The SP should use the formal name (urn:oid ...) to make authorisation decisions etc.

You can see what a FriendlyName is likely to be from the [eduPerson spec](http://software.internet2.edu/eduperson/internet2-mace-dir-eduperson-201602.html) which also gives you the SAML2 Name for the attribute.

The IdP will release what you ask it to release, subject to data laws etc and you need to show you need that attribute to provide a service to the IdP's users. The IdP will obtain the mail attribute from its store, e.g. Active Directory and send it to you in an AttributeStatement, subject to the profile in use, in this case SAML2 WBSSO which requires urn:oid Name and FriendlyName. You shouldn't rely on FriendlyName for authorisation but should use the SAML2 Name instead. FriendlyName is only to show to users if they want to know which attributes have been released by their IdP.

You can see examples of `RequestedAttribute` [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/MetadataForSP).

Comment: So, for parsing purposes, the receiving SP should look at only formal `Name` attribute, which should match the Name requested by the SP (assuming availability, etc.). If the SP requests `Name='urn:oid:2.5.4.42'`, it should be looking for an assertion with `Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42"`. In general it should not be requesting "givenName", nor looking for "givenName".... (I understand that I could request "pizzaSauce" and if the IdP understands, it can return "pizzaSauce", but from a standards perspective, I should be requesting and oid and look to receive the same oid.) Right?

Comment: You should request the profile specific Name. For SAML2 it would be urn:oid... but for SAML1 it would be the fully qualified name of the attribute, e.g. urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:eduPersonTargetedID. In both cases the FriendlyName is just for human readable uses. There's good info in the SAML2 Attribute spec, 2.3 SAML Attribute Naming and 2.3.1 Attribute Name Comparison https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/SpecDrafts-Post2.0/sstc-saml-attribute-x500-cd-01.html